# Solution to linear non-homogeneous differential equations

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I was studying about how Lagrange found a way to solve for the solution to a 1st order linear non-homogeneous differential equation, by using the solution to the homogeneous version of the equation and then finding for the unknown arbitrary function.

The equation
$$
y'+ py = 0
$$
has general solution $y(x) =A e^{\int f(x) \, \text{d}x}$ . Then, for the equation
$$
y' + py = q
$$
how can we say that the solution has to be necessarily of the form $y(x) = A(x) \cdot e^{\int f(x) \, \text{d}x} $ ?

I was wondering by simple analogy (if doing that is alright) :[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, any function $y = y(x)$ is of the form
$$
y(x) = A(x)\cdot e^{\int f(x)\, \text{d}x} \ ,
$$
because we can put
$$
A(x) := \frac{y(x)}{e^{\int f(x)\, \text{d}x}}.
$$
Note that the denominator is always positive, so we can divide.

Comment: This way, can I not say that every function can also be said to be simply of the form y=A(x). Intuitively speaking, how does writing it like y=A(x). exp(g(x)) i.e. by increasing the number of unknown functions get us eventually our function sorted out. Shouldn't we be reducing the number of unknown functions in our solution function. Why did this make any sense to Lagrange?